# How do I care for Adenium Boehmianum?

Tags: flowers, watering, plant-care, succulents

I've had my [Adenium Boehmianum](http://www.plantzafrica.com/plantab/adenium.htm) for almost, em!, maybe 4 years. I leave it in the most sunny place and water on this schedule:

- summer - every week;
- spring/autumn - every fortnight;
- winter - once in a month.

It has leaves 3-4 months a year as it should, but I've never seen it bloom.

What I'm doing wrong? What is the right care scheme for *Adenium Boehmianum*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fascinating plant known as the [Bushman Poison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenium_boehmianum) is native to Namibia and the sap from the plant was used by Bushmen to make poison arrows. This species is known for not flowering as much as some of it's relatives such as [Adenium obesum.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenium_obesum)It is known as a slow grower and can require long periods of dormancy.

Careful attention to their growth cycle should help you bring this plant to flower.  Keep in mind that many plants do not bloom until they are mature and your plant may still be a youngster.

- bright filtered light is best
- never allow the plant to dry out as this can initiate dormancy which prevents the flowering cycle from starting
- use a pot with lots of drainage holes and a free draining soil media with perlite, pumice or even lava rock (popular where I live for use with barbeque's)
- ensure the plant has the bulk of the roots below the caudex (the enlarged water storage area). As a plant from a dry area the bulk of the roots are deep and the upper third of the soil serves to support the stem
- when growth starts in the spring they can be watered daily as long as they do not sit in water and the soil and pot is free draining. If the tips start browning and soil is moist cut back on the watering.
- continue a free watering regime during the spring and fertilize with a product rich in potassium and phosphorus without a too high nitrogen content.
- if you are keeping the plant in a cool climate it will naturally go into dormancy in the fall and drop most of it's leaves.  If kept in a greenhouse it can be considered an evergreen and might be more likely to flower.
- greenhouse conditions are good for growth but can encourage spider mite. Inspect the underside of the leaves regularly.

Comment: Great answer by kevinsky!  Pay attention to the nitrogen!  This plant does well out of doors, I do not believe that indoors this plant would be able to bloom. When a plant needs bright light out of doors, there is no way to recreate that level of 'bright light' indoors unless you add grow lights.  Too high of nitrogen and not ENOUGH light for this plant's needs would be the main reasons for not blooming.